# Cross product, Dot product.

Tags: vectors, inner-products, cross-product

I have been struggling with a homework question and I would like to get some help.

The first section of the question it prove the Triple Product Identity:
$ (\vec u \times \vec v)\times \vec w= (\vec w \cdot \vec u)\vec v - (\vec v \cdot \vec w)\vec u $

Which I proved.

The second section says :

"let $ \vec u , \vec v \neq \vec 0 $ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R} $

Is vector $ \vec w $ exists, such that $ \vec u \times \vec w = \vec v$ and $\vec u \cdot \vec w =\alpha $ ?

In cases where $\vec w$ exists, give example for such $\vec w$.

In cases where $\vec w$ does not exist, explain why."

So in order to find such $\vec w$, $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ must be perpendicular. If $\alpha = 0$ I managed to find such $\vec w$. But when $\alpha \neq 0$ I didn't manage to find such $\vec w$ nor prove that it doesn't exist. I tried to use $ \vec u \times \vec w = \vec v$
and then write $ (\vec u \times \vec w )\times \vec v= \vec v \times \vec v =\vec 0 $ and then use the first section, but it didn't lead me to success.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If such a $\vec w$ exists, then

$$\vec u\times \vec v=\vec u\times(\vec u\times \vec w)=-(\vec u\times \vec w)\times \vec u=-[(\vec u\cdot \vec u)\vec w-(\vec u\cdot \vec w)\vec u]=\alpha \vec u-\vec u^2\vec w$$

from which you can find $\vec w$:

$$\vec w=\frac{1}{\vec u^2}\left(\alpha \vec u-\vec u\times\vec v\right)$$

Then:

$$\vec u\cdot \vec w=\alpha \frac{\vec u^2}{\vec u^2}=\alpha$$

And

$$\vec u\times\vec w=\frac{1}{\vec u^2}(\vec u \times \vec v)\times \vec u=\frac{1}{\vec u^2}\left[(\vec u^2)\vec v-(\vec u\cdot \vec v)\vec u\right]=\vec v-\frac{\vec u\cdot \vec v}{\vec u^2}\vec u$$

Therefore, $\vec u\times \vec w=\vec v$ iff $\vec u\cdot \vec v=0$.